# Div repeat-x surrounded with left and right div

Tags: css, html

http://jsfiddle.net/CApW2/

I can't get it done the right way, left and right div are two images and center is a repeat-x div.
Left and right div must be fixed width and height, center div fixed height but stretched width.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CApW2/1/ ?

Comment: Hmm, when I replace the color for images it is suddenly not fixed anymore: http://jsfiddle.net/CApW2/2/

Comment: coz these pictures are not on the jsfiddle server...?

Comment: When i run the script in a place where there are pictures of that seize it is also dynamic.
If i type A in the div then u see only then image behind the A, i have to type like "dfgsgdsgdsgg" then i see the whole image

Comment: do you require that the left and right "columns" always keep the same height as the  center, - and are they only to contain images that repeat vertically? - and does center have a background-image of it's own too

Comment: Nope left and right div are the rounded corners of a searchbar, the middle is where the search form is gonna be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be either fixed or fluid height. Left and right columns are fixed width, while the center column is fluid. In the source, the side columns are *asides*, and *after* the center column. While you can style each column directly, be careful when editing width/padding/margin/border... you have to make multiple changes in the CSS for each one (but it's grouped and commented fairly well, so you shouldn't have too much trouble).

The CSS:

```
<style>
.two-col {
 overflow:hidden;
}
.two-col > aside {
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 width:250px;
 padding-bottom:10000px;
 margin-bottom:-10000px;
}
.two-col > div {
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 padding-bottom:10000px;
 margin-bottom:-10000px;
}
.two-col.right {
 padding-left:0;
 padding-right:270px; /* Width of aside (width+padding+margin+border) */
}
.two-col.right > aside {
 margin-right:-100%;
}
.two-col.right > div {
 margin-right:10px;
 padding-right:10px;
}
.two-col.left {
 padding-left:260px; /* Width of aside (width+padding+margin+border) */
}
.two-col.left > aside {
 right:260px; /* Width of aside (width+padding+margin+border) */
 margin-left:-100%;
}
.two-col.left > div {
 margin-left:-10px; /* Left padding + left border */
 padding-left:10px;
}
.searchbar.two-col .two-col {
 padding-bottom:10000px;
 margin-bottom:-10000px;
}

.searchbar {
 height:75px; /* Simply remove this to have fluid height */
}
.searchbar .leftColumn { /* Left Column */

}
.searchbar .rightColumn { /* Right Column */

}
.searchbar .centerColumn { /* Center Column */

}

</style>
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="two-col left searchbar">
 <div>
  <div class="two-col right">
   <div class="centerColumn">Center</div>
   <aside class="rightColumn">Right</aside>
  </div>
 </div>
 <aside class="leftColumn">Left</aside>
</div>
```